# Running Homebrew Python in Coderunner

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, coderunner

I installed Python 2.7.12 with Brew on my Mac (Mac OS Sierra 10.12.1) and set my Path to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. Everything just works fine: `python --version` in the terminal gives me *2.7.12*.

For coding I installed Coderunner2. In *Preferences > Advanced* I get the exact same *PATH*: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqY2N.png)

But when I run

`#!/usr/local/bin/python
import platform
print platform.python_version()`

in Coderunner, it gives me *2.7.10*.

What am I missing here? Why isn't Coderunner using Python 2.7.12?

Comment: It seems that your Python code is not properly formated. For example i think the shebang line is incomplete. I try to make the edit myself but SO don't let me.

Comment: I updatet the code (see above). Still it returns 2.7.10 (the Mac OS Version) in the console).

Answer (score 0):

your script's interpreter isn't a valid interpreter (it's a directory on your host, right?) so you must be running that script like:

```
python check_version.py
```

which is running whatever python is in your path first. you should verify which python you're actually running from the command line as show below.

i also run a Homebrew python install (2.7.11), but MacOS comes with its own python installed by default (2.7.10). my homebrew install puts the newer version in /usr/local/bin/python whereas the default MacOS version is in /usr/bin/python, as show below. for your script, make sure your interpreter points to the correct python version you want:

```
wintermute:~ 19:22:47 melgart$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
wintermute:~ 19:22:52 melgart$ /usr/local/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.11
wintermute:~ 19:22:58 melgart$ ls -l /usr/bin/python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66848 Sep 13 20:56 /usr/bin/python*
wintermute:~ 19:23:09 melgart$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.10
wintermute:~ 19:23:13 melgart$
```